# Python threading a subfunction

Tags: python, multithreading

My application is running a in a loop.. sometimes it needs to call a led flash function from the loop. I pretty much did that like this;

```
def led_red_flash(flashcount):
        logging.debug('Starting')

        for l in range(0,flashcount):
                GPIO.output(16,GPIO.HIGH)
                time.sleep(0.1)
                GPIO.output(16,GPIO.LOW)
                time.sleep(0.1)
        logging.debug('Stopping')

while True:
       <do some stuff here>
       t = threading.Thread(name='led_red_flash', target=led_red_flash(100) )
       t.start()
```

This works.. but would there be a day to put all the threading stuff in the def led_red_flash part? As my scripts gets more complex it will make it harder to read. So something like this;

```
while True:
       <do some stuff here>
       led_red_flash(100)
```

The above is a very simplified version of the loop I am running. In the actual script it would not be possible to have multiple instances of led_red_flash run at the same time.. so this is not an issue.

Comment: Are you asking for design review, or do you have a programming issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a wrapper function:

```
def _led_red_flash(flashcount):
    logging.debug('Starting')
    for l in range(0,flashcount):
        GPIO.output(16,GPIO.HIGH)
        time.sleep(0.1)
        GPIO.output(16,GPIO.LOW)
        time.sleep(0.1)
    logging.debug('Stopping')


def led_red_flash(flashcount):
    t = threading.Thread(name='led_red_flash', target=_led_red_flash, args=(100,))
    t.start()
    return t
```

BTW, your original code didn't execute `led_red_flash` in a separate thread. I justed called `led_red_flash` (`led_red_flash(100)`).

You should pass the function itself, not the return value of the function call. See [`threading.Thread`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread).

```
threading.Thread(name='led_red_flash', target=led_red_flash(100))
```

to

```
threading.Thread(name='led_red_flash', target=led_red_flash, args=(100,))
```

Comment: This does the job... I had my trying a wrapper myself but I guess it didn't work because arguments. Thanks.